# Error: read ECONNRESET when resizing image with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I'd like to resize an image stored in Firebase Storage with Firebase Functions.

Based on this example provided by the Firebase team : https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js I tried to write a function triggered by a Database event.

Here is the most interesting part of the code :

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('...').onWrite(event => {

        ...

        // Create thumbnails
        createThumbnail(1, ...);
        createThumbnail(2, ...);
        createThumbnail(3, ...);

         ...

        return; // <- Is this necessary ?
});

function createThumbnail(...) {

    ...

    return bucket
        .file(originalFilepath)
        .download({
            destination: tempFilePath
        })
        .then(() => {

            console.log('OK');

            ...

            // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
            return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', dimension + 'x' + dimension + '>', tempFilePath])
                .then(() => {

                    ....

                    // Uploading the thumbnail.
                    return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
                            destination: thumbnailUrl
                        })
                        .then(() => {

                              ...

                            // Save thumbnailUrl in database
                            return admin.database().ref(...).set(thumbnailUrl);
                        });
                });
        });
}
```

Everything looks fine to me. However the code never go to the `console.log('OK');` and I get this error :

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:569:26)
```

Does somebody know what could be the error?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are returning a Promise which completes before all your asynchronous jobs have completed.

When you do this:

```
createThumbnail(1, ...);
createThumbnail(2, ...);
createThumbnail(3, ...);
...
return;
```

You are starting 3 asynchronous `createThumbnail` tasks but you are returning right away. Therefore the Cloud Functions instance gets shut down and your 3 `createThumbnail` don't have time to complete and that's when you get an `ECONNRESET` error.

Each of the `createThumbnail` returns a Promise. What you need to do is use `Promise.all` to return a `Promise` which completes when the 3 `createThumbnail` Promises are completed:

```
const listOfAsyncJobs = [];
listOfAsyncJobs.push(createThumbnail(1, ...));
listOfAsyncJobs.push(createThumbnail(2, ...));
listOfAsyncJobs.push(createThumbnail(3, ...));
...
return Promise.all(listOfAsyncJobs); // This will ensure we wait for the end of the three aync tasks above.
```